# Pasar a una Activity al pulsar una notificación

Tags: android

Este es el método que se encarga de que cuando reciba la notificación pase a la actividad DrawerActivty.

private void setPendingIntent(){

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(DrawerActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }

}
```

Comment: y cual es la duda/pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esa tarea necesitas utilizar `TaskStackBuilder` y `PendingIntent`.
Segun la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java), deberias hacer lo siguiente:

```
    // Crear un intent para la actividad que deseas iniciar, para el ejemplo 
   //que mencionas que es DrawerActivity
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
// Crear un TaskStackBuilder y agregar el intent creado anteriormente a este, 
// el cual se encargara de inflar el back stack que contiene tu activity.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
// Crear el Pending intent con el back stack creado anteriormente
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Luego de crear el pending intent, debes pasar este a la notificación para que la ejecute cuando la presionas.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
...
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, pero si necesitas algún detalle extra puedes verificarlo en la documentación que esta adjuntado en la respuesta o dejar alguna pregunta en los comentarios. Espero te ayude :)

Comment: ¡¡¡Gracias amigo por la respuesta!!!